# EMC NS-480 Celerra - Way to verify which iSCSI initiators are currently connected to a LUN?

Tags: iscsi, emc, celerra

In the NS-480 or a given Celerra NAS, is there a way to verify which iSCSI initiators are actually **CURRENTLY CONNECTED** to a given LUN?

I can see how to look at the LUN MASKs in Unisphere and see which initiators (in this case ESX hosts) have the right to connect (Grant LUNs), but it doesn't say whether it is or isn't connected.

For instance, on a given LUN MASK it will show a host I know doesn't exist anymore and the LUNs it has rights to see, but I can't find a way to look at the LUN and say "prove to me that this host isn't connected to you".

If it is a CLI command, fine.  I just need to verify certain LUNs that we believe we can remove and reclaim their space, but we would really like to verify whether or not the LUN has any initiators connected to it at all before we remove the LUN.